# django-haystack - accessing request.GET from subclassed FacetedSearchView class

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I have subclassed django-haystack's FacetedSearchView, and want to have an action take place when a specific GET parameter is present in the view's URL. I know exactly how to do this if I had a function-based view, but am at a complete loss when using a subclass of a subclass.

The `request` variable should be available *somehow*. I assume I need to call it up from some kind of `super()` call, maybe in an `__init__()` override? I've tried the following:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MySearch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request.GET.get("date_facet", ""):
        do_something()
```

But it tells me that the returned request object is `None`, though by the URL it clearly shouldn't be.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the request variable is accessible, it just has to be through `self`, which means you can only access it through a function common to the parent class. `__init__` wasn't working, because request isn't defined until later in the parent class. To get things to work I ended up overwriting the get_results() class (originally just `return self.form.search()`), in a way similar to the following:

```
class Foo(ParentClass):
    def get_results(self):
        if 'date_facet' in self.request.GET:
            year = int(self.request.GET['date_facet'])
            return self.form.search().filter(some_filter_function)

        return self.form.search()
```